Error: fetch failed en nextjs
Estoy trabajando con nextjs para crear una página web y estoy intentando tener metadata dinámica para las publicaciones de mi página, ahora, el problema es que al intentarlo me muestra lo siguiente:

Esto me sale cuando quiero entrar a mi publicación, ahora, yo manejo las rutas por el método de App Router y utilizo la funcion generateMetadata en mi codigo de la siguiente forma:
async function getPost(slug: string) {
    const post = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/post/${slug}`).then(res => res.json())
    return post
}

export async function generateMetadata(props: any): Promise<Metadata> {
    const post = await getPost(props.params.slug)
    return {
        title: post.name ?? "Pagina"
    }
}

export default (props: any) => <Post {...props} />

Intente utilizar axios para realizar la petición y me dio el mismo error, luego utilice fetch y tuve el mismo problema. ¿Por lo que no sé si estoy realizando bien la acción o que otra cosa tendría que realizar?

Ya intentaste hacer un CURL a esto? ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/post/${slug} o con POSTMAN algo asi?, alguna forma de verificar que el endpoint de la API si esta funcionando

Si esta funcionando, lo que descubri por despues es que si se utiliza http://localhost/... me da el problema por lo que lo cambie a http://127..., cuando hice el cambio la aplicación funciono correctamente
